# multi-threaded server accepts all multi-threaded clients successfully but only the first client receives data from the server sucessfully

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I'm making a multi-threaded chat client and server. The clients send the dialogue text to the server and the server sends it to the sender client and the other clients, but when the server accepts more than one client, the first client receives and send the data successfully but the rest of the clients only send the data successfully receiving no data. The server receiver the data from all clients successfully. Here's the code:

CLIENT:

```
size_t size;
pthread_t sender;
pthread_t receiver;   
int socket_fd;
int socket_file_transfer= -1500;
 char * nick;

void sig_handler(int signal){
        printf("term signal has been caught\n");

        pthread_cancel(sender);
        pthread_cancel(receiver);   
        close(socket_fd);
        printf("o socket foi fechado\n");        

}

struct file_transfer {
        int host_fd; 
    int file_fd;
    char * filename;
    int started;    
};


void *thread_send(void * socket);
void *thread_receive(void * socket);


int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
    struct sigaction sig_a;
    memset(&sig_a,0,sizeof(sig_a));
    sig_a.sa_handler=&sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sig_a,NULL);
    int port, n;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent * server;
    nick=malloc(strlen(argv[3]));
    memcpy(nick,argv[3],strlen(argv[3]));
    char buffer[255],buffer2[80];
    port=atoi(argv[2]);
    socket_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    bzero((char *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));  
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);    

    server_addr.sin_port=htons(port);

    connect(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
    perror("connect:"); 
    size=strlen(argv[3]);
    //sending nick size
    write(socket_fd,&size,sizeof(size_t));
    //sending NICK string
    write(socket_fd,argv[3],size);  

    char * string=malloc(60);


    size=0;
   bzero(buffer,255);
             int* params;
                params = malloc(sizeof(int));

                *params=socket_fd;
                printf("starting thread with socket %d\n", socket_fd);
                pthread_create(&sender,NULL,&thread_send,(void*) params);

            pthread_create(&receiver,NULL,&thread_receive,(void*) params);

            pthread_join(receiver,NULL);
            pthread_join(sender,NULL);

}

void *thread_send(void * socket){
        char dialogue[270];
                    char buffer[255];
    while(1){


        printf("thread_send running\n");

        read(0,buffer,255);         

        sprintf(dialogue,"[%s] %s",nick,buffer);            


        size_t size=strlen(dialogue);
                    write(*((int *) socket),&size,sizeof(size_t));
            write(*((int *) socket),dialogue,size);
            bzero(buffer,255);

        bzero(buffer,255);
    }

}

void *thread_receive(void * socket){

        struct tm *date;
            time_t tim;
        size_t size=0;
        char buffer[255];
    while(1){
            read(*((int*) socket),&size,sizeof(size_t));

             perror("read size of dialogue from client socket:\n");

            read(*((int *) socket),buffer,size);
            perror("read dialogue from cliente socket");                
            tim=time(NULL);
            date=localtime(&tim);

                    printf("[%d/%d/%d-%d:%d:%d] %s\n",date->tm_mday,date->tm_mon+1,date->tm_year-100,date->tm_hour,date->tm_min,date->tm_sec,buffer);


        bzero(buffer,255);
    }

}
```

SERVER:

```
struct peer {
    char * nick;
    int socketfd;

};

void * thread_client(void * socket);
void del_user(int fd); 

 int npeer=0; 
 struct peer peers[20];


pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        struct sigaction s;
    memset(&s,0,sizeof(s));
    s.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &s, NULL);
    int sockfd,newsockfd,port;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[255];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));      
    int n;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    int reuse_addr = 1; 
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_addr, sizeof(int));

    port=atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(port);

    bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(sockfd,5);
    int fide[2];
    char * token[4];
    //fd_set wfds, tfds,rfds,afds,receiverfds;
                int* params;
    size_t size=0;
    //int status;
    //int newtransferfd=-1;
    char mem[255];
    clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);
    printf("starting accept():\n"); 
    while((newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen)) > 0){

                //RECEBER O TAMANHO DA STRING 
                read(newsockfd,&size,sizeof(size_t));
                //RECEBER A STRING
                read(newsockfd,buffer,size);


                //peers[npeer]=(struct peer *)malloc(sizeof(struct peer));
                peers[npeer].nick=malloc(strlen(buffer));
                strcpy(peers[npeer].nick,buffer);
                printf("nick size: %ld\n",strlen(peers[npeer].nick));
                peers[npeer].socketfd=newsockfd;
                char ip[30];
                getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,clilen,ip,30,NULL,0,NI_NUMERICHOST);
                printf("new client accepted: %s with fd=%d, ip=%s\n",peers[npeer].nick,peers[npeer].socketfd,ip);
                npeer=npeer+1;
                bzero(buffer,255);

                pthread_t *client=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

                params = malloc(sizeof(int));
                *params=newsockfd;
                printf("starting a thread with socket fd=%d\n", newsockfd);
                pthread_create(client,NULL,&thread_client,(void*) params);
                pthread_detach(*client);



            }
}       


void * thread_client(void * socket){
    int sockfd=*((int*) socket);
    free(socket);
    printf("starting thread with socket fd %d\n",sockfd);
    size_t size;
    int status=1;
    char buffer[255];    
 while(status ){  

    size=0;
    if(read(sockfd,&size,sizeof(size_t)) == 0) {
           close(sockfd);
        del_user(sockfd);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    printf("size: %ld\n",size);    
    read(sockfd,buffer,size);    
    printf("%s\n",buffer);    
    if(strstr(buffer,"/exit") != NULL) {
            status=0;

     } else {
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

             for(int i=0;i<npeer;i++){
                    size=strlen(buffer);            

                    //perror("erro");                    
                    printf("socketfd from peers[%d]:%d\n",i,peers[i].socketfd);
                    write(peers[i].socketfd,&size,sizeof(size_t)); 
                        perror("first write");           
                    write(peers[i].socketfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                          perror("second write"); 
                                 bzero(buffer,255);
             }    
             pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }                

 }
    close(sockfd);
    del_user(sockfd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void del_user(int fd){
    printf("del_user(int fd) is being run\n");
    int index=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<npeer;i++){
        if(peers[i].socketfd == fd)
            index=i;    
    }
    if(index!=-1){
        for(int i=index;i<npeer;i++){
            peers[i]=peers[i+1];

        }
        npeer=npeer-1;
        printf("npeer=%d\n",npeer);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

SERVER:

```
$ ./server 12345
starting accept():
nick size: 7
new client accepted: client1 with fd=4, ip=127.0.0.1
starting a thread with socket fd=4
starting thread with socket fd 4
nick size: 7
new client accepted: client2 with fd=5, ip=127.0.0.1
starting a thread with socket fd=5
starting thread with socket fd 5
size: 16
[client1] hello

socketfd from peers[0]:4
first write: Success
second write: Success
socketfd from peers[1]:5
first write: Success
second write: Success
size: 16
[client2] hello

socketfd from peers[0]:4
first write: Success
second write: Success
socketfd from peers[1]:5
first write: Success
second write: Success
```

FIRST CLIENT:

```
$ ./client localhost 12345 client1
connect:: Success
starting thread with socket 3
thread_send running
hello
thread_send running
read size of dialogue from client socket:
: Success
read dialogue from cliente socket: Success
[10/3/20-16:57:39] [client1] hello

read size of dialogue from client socket:
: Success
read dialogue from client socket: Success
[10/3/20-16:57:48] [client2] hello
```

SECOND CLIENT:

```
$ ./client localhost 12345 client2
connect:: Success
starting thread with socket 3
thread_send running
read size of dialogue from client socket:
: Success
read dialogue from cliente socket: Success
[10/3/20-16:57:39] 
hello
thread_send running
read size of dialogue from client socket:
: Success
read dialogue from client socket: Success
[10/3/20-16:57:48]
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `read(0,buffer,255);` - `read` returns the number of characters read. You can't ignore it's return value. `%s",nick,buffer);`  - And I doubt that `read` stores data that are zero terminated. You can't use `%s` with what you received from `read`. Both `listen()` and `bind()` may return an error - you need to check that.

Comment: `del_user()` may be called recurrently - should be protected with mutex. `npeer=npeer+1;` - you should assert that `npeer < 20`. Please fix code indentation and apply some coding style. The `(char*)` casts in `bzero((char *)` make no sense - casting to `void*` is implicit. I recommend [kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).

Comment: To add to what @KamilCuk has already commented, your apps are characterized  by failing to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls:(

Comment: Yes I have to take care of those details. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
    for(int i=0;i<npeer;i++){
            size=strlen(buffer);            
            //perror("erro");                    
            printf("socketfd from peers[%d]:%d\n",i,peers[i].socketfd);
            write(peers[i].socketfd,&size,sizeof(size_t)); 
            perror("first write");           
            write(peers[i].socketfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
            perror("second write"); 
            bzero(buffer,255);
     }
```

Should that bzero(buffer, 255) be there?  It looks wrong, since on the next iteration you take the strlen() of it (spoiler -- it is zero); then write the binary value 0, and the second write writes nothing, because strlen(buffer) is zero.   Btw, you already had strlen(buffer) in size...

Comment: I know there are coding errors on my programs. They are not complete. There is still a lot to be changed, but I found the bug. Like mevets said that bzero(buffer,255) souldn't be there and he's right. that bzero was on the wrong place. I removed it and so far the programs are running as expected.

Comment: I'm going to improve my code, and store the return values of the system calls so that any error can be seen and solved. Thank you all for the help.